# Pop-up abrindo antes de ser clicada pelo botão

Tags: javascript

Queria utilizar um popup numa div mas acontece que a div `popup` aparece na página, sem ser clicada pelo botão. Quando fosse aberto queria fazer parte de trás escura e bloqueada. 
Tentei isso:

```
<div id='abc'>
   (...)

    <div id="popup">
        <label> Popup </label>
    </div>  

    <button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button></div>
```

JavaScript

```
//Function To Display Popup
function div_show() {
    document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}

//Function to Hide Popup
function div_hide(){
    document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Acontece que a div popup aparece na pagina, sem ser clicada pelo butao.

Comment: Depois do botão, ja editei.

Comment: Sua pergunta está um tanto vaga, mas esclareça-me umas dúvidas:
1 - Você está usando jQuery?
2 - Já tentou mudar a propriedade display do css do popup para 'none'? Tente: `<div id="popup" style="display: none;">` ou `<div id="popup" hidden>`

Answer (score 2):

Tem dois problemas no seu código:

- dois ids iguais e isso não pode: `button#popup` e `div#popup`
- você está pedindo para mostrar o `div#abc` mas todo o conteúdo está inserido dentro dele; acredito que quer mostrar somente o `div#popup`

```js
var oPop   = document.getElementById('popup'),
    oBotao = document.getElementById('openpopup');

function div_show() {
    oPop.style.display = "block";
    oBotao.onclick = div_hide;
    oBotao.innerHTML = "Esconder";
}

//Function to Hide Popup
function div_hide() {
    oPop.style.display = "none";
    oBotao.onclick = div_show;
    oBotao.innerHTML = "Popup";
}
```

```html
<div id='abc'>(...)
    <div id="popup" hidden>
        <label>Conteúdo do popup</label>
    </div>
    <button id="openpopup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>
</div>
```

Fiz uma outra versão para simular o efeito *modal* ("parte de trás escura e bloqueada" citada pelo autor da pergunta) onde o `#popup` ocupa toda a largura e altura do `#abc`. Os elementos que em teoria estão por cima ficam inacessíveis. Esse efeito é alcançado com o `position:relative` para o `#abc` e `position:absolute` para o `#popup`. Vale a pena notar o uso do [atributo `hidden` do HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#hidden).

```js
var oPop   = document.getElementById('popup'),
    oBotao = document.getElementById('openpopup');

function div_show() {
  oPop.style.display = "block";
  oBotao.onclick = div_hide;
  oBotao.innerHTML = "Esconder";
}

function div_hide() {
  oPop.style.display = "none";
  oBotao.onclick = div_show;
  oBotao.innerHTML = "Popup";
}
```

```css
#abc, #popup {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
}
#abc {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  position: relative;
}
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}
#popup div {
  padding:1em;
  background-color: #ccccff;
  color: #fff;
  width: 10%;
  margin: auto;
  
}
#openpopup {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id='abc'>
  <div id="popup" hidden>
    <div><label>Conteúdo do popup</label></div>
  </div>
  <h3>(...)</h3>
  <a href="#">(...)</a>
  <br>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<button id="openpopup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente este código html, deste site: http://www.botecodigital.info/jquery/criando-uma-janela-modal-simples-com-jquery/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Janela modal</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("a[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();

                    var id = $(this).attr("href");

                    var alturaTela = $(document).height();
                    var larguraTela = $(window).width();

                    //colocando o fundo preto
                    $('#mascara').css({'width':larguraTela,'height':alturaTela});
                    $('#mascara').fadeIn(1000); 
                    $('#mascara').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

                    var left = ($(window).width() /2) - ( $(id).width() / 2 );
                    var top = ($(window).height() / 2) - ( $(id).height() / 2 );

                    $(id).css({'top':top,'left':left});
                    $(id).show();   
                });

                $("#mascara").click( function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(".window").hide();
                });

                $('.fechar').click(function(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    $("#mascara").hide();
                    $(".window").hide();
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">

        .window{
            display:none;
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            background:#FFF;
            z-index:9900;
            padding:10px;
            border-radius:10px;
        }

        #mascara{
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            z-index:9000;
            background-color:#000;
            display:none;
        }

        .fechar{display:block; text-align:right;}

        </style>

    </head>


    <body>
        <a href="#janela1" rel="modal">Janela modal</a>
        <a href="#janela2" rel  ="modal">Janela 2 modal</a>


        <div class="window" id="janela1">
            <a href="#" class="fechar">X Fechar</a>
            <h4>Primeira janela moda</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam venenatis auctor tempus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
            <p>Morbi dui lacus, placerat eget pretium vehicula, mollis id ligula. Nulla facilisi. </p>
        </div>

        <div class="window" id="janela2">
            <a href="#" class="fechar">X Fechar</a>
            <h4>Formulario</h4>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
                <br />

                <label for="nome">Senha:</label>
                <input type="text" name="senha" id="senha">
                <br />

                <input type="submit" value="enviar">

            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- mascara para cobrir o site --> 
        <div id="mascara"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema está no css.A div(background) de tras deve ter um z-index maior que o button mas mais pequeno que o popup e deve tambem ter medidas a 100%.

Aqui vai um link que talve o ajude :
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k637w23a/)